# Where and how should I define the spl_autoload_register?

Tags: php, autoload

Basically, I have the php class `myclass` located in `root/lib/php/` and I want the classes the autoload from there, whenever I call them.

Now I am trying to do this in the main index.php file. How and where should I properly define `spl_autoload_register` so that I can use it for static class: `myclass::mymethod()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically autoload coded is included in a config file or some other file that is included with each pageload and contains common code required for the site to run.

Static calls to class methods is no different then instanciating a class and calling a method as far as autoload is concerned.

An example:

```
/*** nullify any existing autoloads ***/
spl_autoload_register(null, false);

/*** specify extensions that may be loaded ***/
spl_autoload_extensions('.Class.php');

/*** class Loader ***/
define('BASE_APP_PATH', '/path/to/root/web/');
function classLoader($class){
     $filename = $class . '.Class.php';
     $file = BASE_APP_PATH.'classes/' . $filename;
     if (file_exists($file)){
        include $file;
     }
}

/*** register the loader functions ***/
spl_autoload_register('classLoader');
```

You then can do this without explicitly requiring the class' file:

```
echo SomeClass::staticCall();
```

Comment: Okay, I have a session file that goes everywhere. My question is, how is this different from actually including the files? I thought I could define this within the class itself and then simply call the methods without instantiating, or in my case without including that session file? I was trying to do it the other way around. Have a method within a class that includes the session file, and simply call a static method when I need to render a page. Oh well, I guess it's not possible in the end. Nonetheless, thank you for your help.